# Lilypond doesnt appear in apps

Tags: software-installation

I used Linux Ubuntu 15.04 and installed lilypond from terminal

```
~$ sudo apt-get install lilypond
```

But it didnt appear in application.

when i try open via terminal

```
~$ lilypond

GNU LilyPond 2.18.2
Usage: lilypond [OPTION]... FILE...
Typeset music and/or produce MIDI from FILE.
LilyPond produces beautiful music notation.
For more information, see http://lilypond.org
Options:
-d, --define-default=SYM[=VAL]      set Scheme option SYM to VAL (default: #t).
   Use -dhelp for help.
  -e, --evaluate=EXPR                 evaluate scheme code
 -f, --formats=FORMATs               dump FORMAT,...  Also as separate options:
      --pdf                           generate PDF (default)
      --png                           generate PNG
      --ps                            generate PostScript
  -h, --help                          show this help and exit
  -H, --header=FIELD                  dump header field FIELD to file
                                        named BASENAME.FIELD
  -I, --include=DIR                   add DIR to search path
  -i, --init=FILE                     use FILE as init file
  -j, --jail=USER, GROUP, JAIL, DIR   chroot to JAIL, become USER:GROUP
                                        and cd into DIR
  -l, --loglevel=LOGLEVEL             print log messages according to 
LOGLEVEL.  Possible values are:
                                        NONE, ERROR, WARNING, BASIC, 
PROGRESS, INFO (default) and DEBUG.
  -o, --output=FILE                   write output to FILE (suffix will be added)
      --relocate                      relocate using directory of lilypond program
  -s, --silent                        no progress, only error messages (equivalent to loglevel=ERROR)
  -v, --version                       show version number and exit
  -V, --verbose                       be verbose (equivalent to 
loglevel=DEBUG)
  -w, --warranty                      show warranty and copyright
```

Is lilypond already instaling properly? How do open or launch lilypond?

Answer (score 0):

`lilypond` is installed properly.

Run with

```
lilypond <your_file>
```

as described in the help. More information with `man lilypond`

> Usage: lilypond [OPTION]... FILE...
>   Typeset music and/or produce MIDI from FILE.

It doesn't appears in Applications, because there is no GUI, (graphical user interface) only a CLI (command line interface)

---

*Example*

1. Create a new file `test.ly`

   ```
   cd
   nano test.ly
   ```
2. Add the lines below

   ```
   \version "2.18.2"
   {
     c' e' g' e'
   }
   ```
3. Compile

   ```
   lilypond test.ly
   ```
4. Open the result

   ```
   xdg-open test.pdf
   ```

   [image]

---

*Another example*

1. Create a new source (`test2.ly`) file and add

   ```
   upper = \relative c'' {
     \clef treble
     \key c \major
     \time 4/4

     a4 b c d
   }

   lower = \relative c {
     \clef bass
     \key c \major
     \time 4/4

     a2 c
   }

   \score {
     \new PianoStaff <<
       \set PianoStaff.instrumentName = #"Piano  "
       \new Staff = "upper" \upper
       \new Staff = "lower" \lower
     >>
     \layout { }
     \midi { }
   }
   ```
2. Compile

   ```
   lilypond test2.ly
   ```
3. And open the result

   ```
   xdg-open test2.pdf
   ```

   [image]

Comment: @AgungWahyudi As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)